# How to schedule a task using SYSTEM account with console window open

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I wanted to auto create schedule task and avoid using specific user credentials and thus decided to use SYSTEM. Also require with console window open when the task is running.

Here is an sample batch file command.

"cmd /k ipconfig /all"

If i configure the task scheduler with user account and "Run only when user is logged on", i am getting the expected result. But if the same can be achievable to configure with SYSTEM account, so that all logged in users can see the log flying by the window ?

---

Currently our scenario is one of the user is logging in, executing the files (which connects to third party application) and it keeps running without any issue and the user disconnects his session. Whenever he wants to check any error, do login and check the same in the running cmd windows, then he disconnects his session. It works well for a longer time.

But recently we are facing the issue for the processes are getting terminated unknowingly (particularly on last 2 weekends). Unfortunately, we are unable to identify the issue and we suspect that the user session (where the script is running) is getting logged off.

We have configured the error log, but unfortunately it is generating empty log file on the time of whenever we restarting the process and no abnormal termination log files. And the event log analysis also not helped here.

Could someone provide me the suitable solution on this case ?

Requirement: The processes need to run 24/7 with console window open. If it crashed for any reason, then it generate the proper error log.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But if the same can be achievable to configure with SYSTEM account, so that
>   all logged in users can see the log flying by the window ?

This is not how sessions work under windows. Fundamentally not possibly. There is no "see", it is a windows LIVES in a desktop session or not. And only in ONE.

So, no, this can not be done.

You can start a service and have every user start a program to show the log (which it gets from the service), but that is a way more complicated approach.